# ADACOS implementataion on colab TPU throws error

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, google-colaboratory, tpu

I'm trying to implement Adaptive cosine scaling on keras and train it on cloud TPU.
I have tried a lot but am unable to fix the following error.
I feel the error is either with tf.acos or self.s.assign.

The following is the ADACOS implementation im trying on colab TPU

```
import math, os
import tensorflow.keras as keras
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Layer, Input, Dense, Flatten, BatchNormalization, Conv2D, Activation, MaxPooling2D, Dropout
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
from tensorflow.keras import regularizers
from tensorflow.keras.datasets import mnist
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import Callback, ModelCheckpoint, TerminateOnNaN
from tensorflow.keras import backend as K
import tensorflow_probability as tfp

class AdaCos(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
  def __init__(self, n_classes=5, m=0.50, regularizer=None, **kwargs):
    super(AdaCos, self).__init__(**kwargs)
    self.n_classes = n_classes
    self.s = tf.Variable(initial_value=tf.constant(math.sqrt(2)*math.log(n_classes-1)), dtype = tf.float32,trainable=False,aggregation=tf.VariableAggregation.MEAN)
    self.m = m
    self.regularizer = regularizers.get(regularizer)
    self.pi = math.pi


  def build(self, input_shape):
    super(AdaCos, self).build(input_shape[0])
    self.W = self.add_weight(name='W',
                            shape=(input_shape[0][-1], self.n_classes),
                            initializer='glorot_uniform',
                            trainable=True,
                            regularizer=self.regularizer)
    
  def call(self, inputs):
    x, y = inputs
    # normalize feature
    x = tf.nn.l2_normalize(x, axis=1)
    # normalize weights
    W = tf.nn.l2_normalize(self.W, axis=0)
    # dot product
    logits = x @ W
    
    # add margin
    # clip logits to prevent zero division when backward
    theta = tf.acos(K.clip(logits, -1.0 + K.epsilon(), 1.0 - K.epsilon()))

    B_avg = tf.where(y < 1, tf.exp(self.s*logits), tf.zeros_like(logits))
    B_avg = tf.reduce_mean(tf.reduce_sum(B_avg, axis=1), name='B_avg')
    theta_class = tf.gather(theta, tf.math.argmax(tf.cast(y, tf.int32),axis=1), name='theta_class')
    theta_med = tfp.stats.percentile(theta_class, q=50)

    with tf.control_dependencies([theta_med, B_avg]):
      temp_s = tf.cast(tf.math.log(B_avg)  / tf.cos(tf.minimum(self.pi/4, theta_med)),tf.float32)
      self.s.assign(temp_s)
      logits = self.s * logits 
      out = tf.nn.softmax(logits)
    return out

  def compute_output_shape(self, input_shape):
    return (None, self.n_classes)
```

The model is as follows:

```
def create_model():
  weight_decay = 1e-1
  inputs = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=[*IMAGE_SIZE, 3])
  pretrained_model = tf.keras.applications.Xception(input_tensor=inputs, include_top=False)
  pretrained_model.trainable = True
  y = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(5))
  x = tf.keras.layers.GlobalAveragePooling2D()(pretrained_model.output)
  output = AdaCos(5, regularizer=regularizers.l2(weight_decay))([x, y])
  model = tf.keras.Model([inputs,y], output, name="EfficientNet")

  model.compile(
    optimizer='adam',
    loss = 'categorical_crossentropy',
    metrics=['accuracy'] , experimental_run_tf_function=False
  )
  return model

with tpu_strategy.scope(): # creating the model in the TPUStrategy scope means we will train the model on the TPU
  model = create_model()
model.summary()
```

When I fit the model it throws this error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
UnimplementedError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-13-0909f5f73843> in <module>()
      1 history = model.fit(training_dataset, validation_data=validation_dataset,
----> 2                     steps_per_epoch=train_steps, epochs=EPOCHS, callbacks=[lr_callback])
      3 
      4 final_accuracy = history.history["val_accuracy"][-5:]
      5 print("FINAL ACCURACY MEAN-5: ", np.mean(final_accuracy))

12 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/six.py in raise_from(value, from_value)

UnimplementedError: 9 root error(s) found.
  (0) Unimplemented: {{function_node __inference_train_function_156257}} Compilation failure: HLO get-dimension-size is not implemented on TPU.
    TPU compilation failed
     [[{{node tpu_compile_succeeded_assert/_13941289253070589622/_6}}]]
     [[tpu_compile_succeeded_assert/_13941289253070589622/_6/_251]]
  (1) Unimplemented: {{function_node __inference_train_function_156257}} Compilation failure: HLO get-dimension-size is not implemented on TPU.
    TPU compilation failed
     [[{{node tpu_compile_succeeded_assert/_13941289253070589622/_6}}]]
     [[TPUReplicate/_compile/_8068376899169244840/_5/_276]]
  (2) Unimplemented: {{function_node __inference_train_function_156257}} Compilation failure: HLO get-dimension-size is not implemented on TPU.
    TPU compilation failed
     [[{{node tpu_compile_succeeded_assert/_13941289253070589622/_6}}]]
     [[tpu_compile_succeeded_assert/_13941289253070589622/_6/_265]]
  (3) Unimplemented: {{function_node __inference_train_function_156257}} Compilation failure: HLO get-dimension-size is not implemented on TPU.
    TPU compilation failed
     [[{{node tpu_compile_succeeded_assert/_13941289253070589622/_6}}]]
     [[tpu_compile_succeeded_assert/_13941289253070589622/_6/_237]]
  (4) Unimplemented: {{function_node __inference_train_function_156257}} Compilation failure: HLO get-dimension-size is not implemented on TPU.
    TPU compilation failed
     [[{{node tpu_compile_succeeded_assert/_13941289253070589622/_6}}]]
     [[tpu_compile_succeeded_assert/_13941289253070589622/_6/_293]]
  (5) Unimplemented: {{function_node __inference_train_function_156257}} Compilation failure: HLO get-dimension-size is not implemented on TPU.
    TPU compilation failed
     [[{{node tpu_compile_succeeded_assert/_13941289253070589622/_6}}]]
     [[tpu_compile_succeeded_assert/_13941289253070589622/_6/_223]]
  (6) Unimplemented: {{function_node __inference_train_function_156257}} Compilation failure: HLO get-dimension-size is not implemented on TPU.
    TPU compilation failed
     [[{{node tpu_compile_succeeded_assert/_13941289253070589622/_6}}]]
     [[tpu_compile_succeeded_assert/_13941289253070589622/_6/_307]]
  (7) Unimplemented: {{function_node __inference_train_function_156257}} Compilation failure: HLO get-dimension-size is not implemented on TPU.
    TPU compilation failed
     [[{{node tpu_compile_succeeded_assert/_13941289253070589622/_6}}]]
  (8) Unimplemented: {{function_node __inference_train_function_156257}} Compilation failure: HLO get-dimension-size is not implemented on TPU.
    TPU compilation failed
     [[{{node tpu_compile_succeeded_assert/_13941289253070589622/_6}}]]
     [[tpu_compile_succeeded_assert/_13941289253070589622/_6/_209]]
0 successful operations.
0 derived errors ignored.
```